# Convert BitmapImage into Base64String in WinRT

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, winrt-xaml, winrt-async

I want to convert BitmapImage into base64string in my windows 8.1 apps.
**CODE:**

```
protected void UpdateSignatureAsync(BitmapImage bitmapImage, string fileName, long vehicleInsRecID)
{


    WriteableBitmap writimage = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImage.PixelWidth, bitmapImage.PixelHeight);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        WriteableBitmapExtensions.FromStream(writimage, ms);
        Stream s1 = writimage.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
        s1.CopyTo(ms);
        writimage.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
        var ic = new ImageCapture
        {
            ImageBinary = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray()),/// this line
            CaseServiceRecId = vehicleInsRecID,
            FileName = fileName
        };
        await UpdateImageAsync(ic);
    }
```

Comment: and what is the exact problem that you're facing?

Comment: ... so you want to save the image data as Bitmap? or are you trying to save raw pixels?

Comment: This code is wrong. BitmapImage is not converting WriteableBitmap .It is just taking height  & width of BitmapImage  Byte array(ms.ToArray())  is every byte is 0.

Comment: You used `await` in a method that is not `async` - something else is wrong with your sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact answer for your question, but if you have a `StorageFile` which is an image, then you can convert this image to a `Base64` string using the `GetBase64FromImageFile` method in the following class:

```
public static class ImageHash
{
    private static async Task<string> GetBase64FromImageFile(StorageFile file)
    {
        return ComputeHash(await ConvertToByteArray(file));
    }

    private static string ComputeHash(byte[] buffer)
    {
        IBuffer input = buffer.AsBuffer();
        IBuffer hashed = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Sha1).HashData(input);

        return CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(hashed);
    }

    public async static Task<byte[]> ConvertToByteArray(StorageFile imageFile)
    {
        byte[] srcPixels;
        RandomAccessStreamReference streamRef =
            RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromFile(imageFile);

        using (IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType fileStream =
            await streamRef.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(fileStream);
            BitmapFrame frame = await decoder.GetFrameAsync(0);

            // I know the parameterless version of GetPixelDataAsync works for this image
            PixelDataProvider pixelProvider = await frame.GetPixelDataAsync();
            srcPixels = pixelProvider.DetachPixelData();
        }

        return srcPixels;
    }
}
```